# Parsing XML as PHP with web.config

Tags: php, asp.net, xml, azure

I have an XML document where I need to place some information about IP. The problem is that making XML parse as PHP in Apache can be done with `.htaccess`, but when I moved to Azure, it became harder.
What I tried:

- web.config

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>

  <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
          <staticContent>
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="text/php" />
       </staticContent>
      </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
  ```
- applicationHost.config

  ```
  <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
             <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="text/php" />
        </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  ```
- .htaccess: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .xml`

But none of this works. I get error for not correct XML. Need help. The XML File:

```
<config>
     <settings ip="<?php /*getting external IP...*/ ?>" port="1010"/>
</config>
```

**UPDATE**
I took a look at the headers and it says that `Content-Type` is `application/xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found no way except making separate PHP file.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
$myip = "0.0.0.0";
echo '<config><settings ip="' . $myip . '" port="1010"/>';
include("myxml.xml");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle situations like this, when I either do not have the time to dig into the server configuration, or am not able to modify the server configuration is to create a directory with the name of the file I want to parse as PHP, and an index.php within that file that handles whatever needs to be done.  For example:

`myxml.xml/index.php` (which would be exactly like the index.php in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37628203/256305))
`myxml.xml/myxml.xml` (which can include php code)

In this configuration, client requests for `myxml.xml` get redirected to `myxml.xml/index.php`, which then serves `myxml.xml/myxml.xml`